# Fetch request with multiple predicates?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, core-data

I have an entity `Tags`, and I want to perform a fetch to get all `Tags` and assign that to a `NSFetchedResultsController`. But, I want the first object in the fetched results to be the `Tag` with `tagName` property equal to `"All"`, then the rest sorted by alphabetical order. Currently I'm doing this, which just returns all of the tags in alphabetical order, but I want the tag named `"All"` to be first always, then the rest in alphabetical order.

```
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription 
                                   entityForName:@"Tag" inManagedObjectContext:appDelegate.managedObjectContext];

[fetchRequest setEntity:entity];
NSSortDescriptor *lastDescriptor =
[[[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"tagName"ascending:YES selector:@selector(localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:)] autorelease];      

[fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:lastDescriptor]];
```

Comment: can you post the method localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare ? I can create  a new solution but I think the best option is to optimize your actual solution.

Comment: That's not my method..it's just a default method that's given

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use a comparator created by you, not one default, so you can do something like that:

```
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription 
                               entityForName:@"Tag" inManagedObjectContext:appDelegate.managedObjectContext];

[fetchRequest setEntity:entity];
NSSortDescriptor *lastDescriptor =
[[[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"tagName" ascending:YES comparator:^NSComparisonResult(NSString* tag1, NSString* tag2) {

    if ([tag1 isEqualToString:@"All"]) return NSOrderedAscending;
    if ([tag2 isEqualToString:@"All"]) return NSOrderedDescending;

    return [tag1 compare:tag2];
}] autorelease];      

[fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:lastDescriptor]];
```

**Edit**

Like @Andrew Madsen told you can use a comparator, I do not see that he already have answered your question.

You can use a selector too, just need to implement it in your model a method to do the comparison, what I made a mistake and believed that was what you are doing, from apple doc:

> *selector*
>
> The method to use when comparing the properties of objects,
>   for example caseInsensitiveCompare: or localizedCompare:. The selector
>   must specify a method implemented by the value of the property
>   identified by keyPath. The selector used for the comparison is passed
>   a single parameter, the object to compare against self, and must
>   return the appropriate NSComparisonResult constant. The selector must
>   have the same method signature as:
>   - (NSComparisonResult)localizedCompare:(NSString *)aString

Comment: One very small nitpick, if tag1 and tag2 are both "All" the comparator should probably return NSOrderedSame. Probably won't matter in reality though.

Comment: Yeah, you are right, but I think this is not relevant for this specific case.

Comment: Actually, this doesn't work properly when I have tagNames that start with numbers. How can the above code be edited to make it so that "All" appears even on top of tags with numbers?

Comment: This code is supposed to work even with tagNames that start with number, because it will always return the tag that is equal to All first, what you need to be sure is that your tag is really equal to All, maybe you need to trim it or use something like: `[[obj1 lowercaseString] isEqualToString:@"all"]`

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with NSSortDescriptor itself using a custom compare method. However, you can also sort the results of the fetch request after you get them back. NSArray has a method called `-sortedArrayUsingComparator:` that allows you to sort the array using a block, making custom sort behavior like this pretty easy. See below for an example:

```
NSArray *sortedResults = [results sortedArrayUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(id obj1, id obj2) {
    NSString *tag1 = [obj1 tagName];
    NSString *tag2 = [obj2 tagName];

    BOOL tag1IsAll = [tag1 isEqualToString:@"All"];
    BOOL tag2IsAll = [tag2 isEqualToString:@"All"];
    if (tag1IsAll && !tag2IsAll) return NSOrderedAscending;
    if (tag2IsAll && !tag1IsAll) return NSOrderedDescending;

    return [tag1 compare:tag2];
}];
```

Comment: But I need it to be in an NSFetchedResultsController since that I'm using a UITableView, and that would be my data source.

Comment: Can't I somehow apply this method you added in the sort descriptor selector option?

Comment: Yes, sorry. I didn't really keep in mind that you're using an NSFetchedResultsController. Too early in the morning for me ;-). ggrana's answer shows how you can do this same thing with an NSSortDescriptor.